# What does Carolinus's letter say?

Tags: languages, translation, the-flight-of-dragons

In the 1982 film *The Flight of Dragons*, the Green Wizard Carolinus writes a letter to his allies, the Yellow Wizard Lo Tae Zhao and the Blue Wizard Solarius.  We hear the wizards reading from the letter, and also see a brief glimpse of the letter itself:

[image: screenshot of Carolinus's Arabic-looking letter]

The writing system looks like it uses the Arabic alphabet, or something like it.  Does the letter shown in this film still say anything in any known natural or invented language, or is it just nonsensical scribbles dreamed up by some artist working for the film?  If the text is comprehensible, what language is it in, and do the words have any relevance to the plot?

Comment: "The Flight of Dragons was based on the theories of dragon flight created by Peter Dickinson in his semi-serious book (The Flight of Dragons) and the fantasy novel "The Dragon and the George" by Gordon R. Dickson.